What is the laser power and nm required to cut a row of paper with these specifications?
Here are my specifics. I am looking at quickly cutting a wet-paper-like material approximately 0.2 inches thick. The material stands up on its own and is separated approximately 0.33 inches apart each. How much would a laser need in power and nm to cut through 2 feet of the material arranged within approximately 250 milliseconds? I was able to find some information on this, and I have estimated that I would need a laser in a 900-1100 nm range of about 40 watts. Still, I am unsure since I have limited knowledge of these calculations and this is from comparison to a post I found regarding regular paper cutting but no time information or info about when the paper was wet. I would need some lens to make sure the beam doesn't diverge far within 2 feet. I apologize if this is not the correct format for asking questions of this type.

I’m voting to close this question because this is a materials science/applied physics question.

wet-paper-like material ... what liquid?

Ladle, is that essentially 46 sheets to penetrate? Or about 9 inches of material? Perhaps it would help if you provided a drawing. Have you worked out the specific heat and the heat of evaporation for the material (and that temperature, too?)

you could try using shears

From my experience with a 40W CO2 laser, I think cutting 5mm of wet material at any speed is going to take maybe 1kW of optical power. Maybe consider water jet.

Lasers can cut things when the beam is focused to a spot and may be able to support a depth of field working area of a few millimeters to maybe a centimeter (with a large amount of laser power). You will never cut a stack two feet thick.
You may find some other technology to do this but think loads of coin.
